# how to change thread user in c?

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi, permissions

I have a program with 2 threads. I want the first thread to be run under user permissions of USER_1, and the second under USER_2 of Windows. When I log in as USER_1, both threads have USER_1 permissions. How can I change the user of the thread!?

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you're trying to do? Are you trying to assign roles to threads? Are you using .NET? Win32? Something else all together?

Comment: Simply, USER_1 creates a folder on first thread. USER_2 should not be able to delete that folder on second thread.

Comment: @Pazis, USER_2 can corrupt the USER_1 thread stack and do whatever they want in USER_1's context, since they share an address space

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign an impersonation token to a thread using [SetThreadToken()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379590%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It may not be very trivial to do, though.

Comment: How can I use it!? May you please give an example?

Comment: `SetThreadToken()` is not the only way to impersonate a user. There is also `LogonUser()` and. `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser()`, for instance.

Comment: I still can't get it to work. Mainly because I'm somehow new to C. Anyone can give me a piece of code, please!

Comment: Well! I finally did it with setuid function! Thanks everyone!